# Apply Countifs function to last non empty row in Excel

Tags: excel

I have 4 columns in excel. Data for first three column is getting populated by using Macro. On 4th column, I have applied Excel function countifs. I have applied it till 100th row. So if data is more than 100 row, function does not get apply to remaining rows. I want that, this formula should apply automatically to all those rows which contain non empty data may be those are less than 100 or more than 100. Please help.

Comment: I tried "= COUNTIFS(B:B,B:B,A:A,A:A)" but did not work

Comment: I am counting those rows having same "Column A and Column B" values.

Comment: @Coder157 from what i understand you just need to correct your formula to: `=COUNTIFS(B:B,B1,A:A,A1)`

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=SUM((A:A=B:B)*(A:A<>""))
```

entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Apply something like this to every cell in your 4th column

```
=IF(expression, when-true, else)
```

In *expression* you want to check if A and B are valid and probably your *else* will be an empty value